# Nautilus treats OpenOffice Files as Archives/Opens with Archive Manager

Tags: nautilus

I recently installed OpenOffice, replacing LibreOffice. Nautilus treats .ods and .odt files as archives, and opens them with the Archive Manager.  OpenOffice does not show up as an available application (either in File name >Properties >3rd Tab >Open with; OR with Right click file name >Open with).

How can I add OpenOffice to the list of available applications?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and OpenOffice 4.

Answer (score 0):

In `\usr\share\applications\` there are *.desktop* files for LibreOffice, e.g. *libreoffice-writer.desktop*. There should be similar files for OpenOffice, which should be installed from the [package *DEBS/desktop-integration/*](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=73254). If that does not work, you can manually copy the existing LibreOffice desktop files and modify them for the Open Office applications.

These *.desktop* files add items to the *Open with* menu. Alternatively, there are similar files in `\home\user\.local\share\applications\` which can be used to add menu entries for a mime type. For example, the following was written to open a JSON file in wine with JSONedit (which had been copied to a local directory, WinApps), and the file was saved as *wine-extension-json.desktop*:

`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=JSONedit
MimeType=document/json;
Exec=wine "/home/user/Winapps/jsonedit/JSONedit.exe" z:%f
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/usr/share/icons/oxygen/48x48/apps/kdf.png`

Comment: Thanks.  (Re)installing desktop-integration did the job.